# onTick java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android

i have a yahtzee (dice game) where a player rolls 5 dice. i use a countdown timer to do a small animation where all of the dice are displayed as a "1" then "2" then "3" then "4" then all of the dice should go to a random number.  on the emulator and any phone i test it on, this seems to work correctly 100% of the time however... since i have released my game on the android market i have gotten hundreds of crash reports complaining of this error, and it seems have something to do with this animation.  judging from the user messages, it looks like it goes to all "6's" then gets a force close.

here is the code:

```
public void animateDize(){
    new CountDownTimer(900,150){ 

        Integer j = 0;

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                if(DieSet[i]== 0){                                      // If dice are not clicked, animate them
                    imageButtons[i].setBackgroundResource(imageRes[j]);
                }
            }
            j ++;          
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            randomDize();                                               // Set dice to random values
            }
    }.start();
}
```

Here is the error i am getting back from my crash report.  is there perhaps i better way i could be animating this instead?

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at
>   com.surreall.yatzee.yatzee$7.onTick(yatzee.java:649) at
>   android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:124) at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based just on the code we see here, it looks like `j` will become larger and larger until it's too large to be an index into the array `imageRes`, at which point you'll get this exception. If we saw more code, I might have a different interpretation, but based just on this, that seems a likely explanation.

Comment: i think you are correct but i am missing why. first j is set to 0, then the countdown timer starts and runs for 6 iterations (900/150), so it should only go to the 6th index of imageRes.  why would it sometimes fail, and sometimes not?  which other part of the code?  the stuff for ramdomDize() etc?

Comment: You're assuming that there will be exactly six ticks, but that's not necessarily a valid assumption for all devices in the real world. What if an interrupt delays the system clock from being updated for even one millisecond? Then you'll get seven instead of six. Basically I think you just need to add a guard clause to limit the upper bound of `j`.

Comment: ah this must be it. i have changed it so that once it reaches 6 it starts back at 1 again and repeats doing this cycle indefinitely if necessary. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `j`'s value will be 6 on the 7'th tick of the `onTick()` method.  I'm assuming you only have 6 dice images, which means that after it reaches `imageRes[5]` it will attempt to go to `imageRes[6]`, which I'm assuming doesn't exist (index value of 6 is the 7th index value, and a dice only has 6 sides).  Thats the only explanation I can see.